# Classic ASP and SSL in a folder

Tags: ssl, asp-classic

We have a folder in a classic asp site that has ssl set up for that folder. It works but when you load the first page within the folder and then follow a hyperlink to another page in the folder you get kicked back to the page outside the folder which led into the https stuff.

Repeat the process (*follow link on non https page > go to https folder > follow link to other page in https folder*) and it all works fine, for a random number of hops between pages in the https folder, then bang, kicked out again.

I have noticed that the session ID changes all the time when hopping between pages in the https folder. Someone said it was due to IE compatabilty mode swapping but I have forced the thing with a header and using IE dev tools (miss you Firebug) I see the mode stays constant. any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue with another project last year. @padas is correct. Sessions on http and https are different and the server will have a problem with it.  The option we went for was to https the whole site.  It makes sense anyway and helps the user gain confidence in what they are browsing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your traversing between http and https and that will change the session id.  If your pages are using session id's to track people you will have issues.  You are better off dropping a cookie or forcing https.